# It was established on a rocky foundation

Tags: meaning, adjectives, ambiguity

> It was established on a *rocky* foundation.

Does it mean  *steady* or *shaky*?

Comment: There's no way of knowing. What is "it"? What is the context?

Comment: Knowing the source of the example and what else was said about the "rocky" foundation would help determine if the source meant "shaky" or merely misused "rocky" and perhaps mean "rock-solid" foundation.  The more you bring to your questions, the better the answers! :-)

Answer (score 9):

It depends upon the context.

If we're talking about a house, rocky would take its primary meaning of *consisting or formed of rock*, which would tend to imply that it was fairly steady.

If we're speaking metaphorically, however, rocky is likely taking its secondary meaning of *tending to rock or shake; unsteady* instead. This is actually an idiomatic expression which means that something was poorly conceived or incorrectly implemented from its start.

Comment: Without further context it's simply not possible to justify that assertion. A significant proportion (possibly even *most*) written instances of ["on a rocky foundation"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22on+a+rocky+foundation%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) clearly mean *on a **solid/stable** foundation*. I think largely because of that ambiguity it's not really "idiomatic" compared to [on a shaky foundation](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+a+rocky+foundation%2Con+a+shaky+foundation&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) today, as that chart shows.

Comment: While you're probably right, there really isn't enough to go on from the OP's question to say with all certainty that is what was meant.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, jinx!

Comment: @Kristina: Check out my link. I think that's proof enough that a century or two ago, a *rocky foundation* was normally "solid". Today we use *rocky* differently; consequently, people would tend to avoid OP's form completely these days.

Comment: I hadn't realized that the OP might have run across a literal usage of this phrase, and have edited my response to reflect that. Thanks for the notes guys!

Comment: @MasonHemmel That's probably the best anyone can do until/if we ever know the source of OP's example - old and probably literal, or new idiom. :-)

Comment: It's a case of which metaphor for _rocky_ is being employed. This probably comes from an old pun in the New Testament about _St Peter_ and Latin _petris_ 'rock'. Since _rocky_ can be used in many different ways in many different metaphors in English, that adds to the joke.

Comment: The only context I can think of where *rocky* is routinely used today to mean *rock-like, made of rock* is *[terrestrial planet, telluric planet or **rocky planet**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrestrial_planet) - a planet that is composed primarily of silicate rocks or metals*. I barely recognise the sense *rocky = shaky* outside of metaphoric references to relationships, phases in life, etc.